# Can i use private properties in Typegoose?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, private, typegoose

In the company where I work, we are creating an APP made in Nodejs we are question about implement Typegoose.
We have a question about implementing. We don't find a way to put a "private" property.
How can i do that?

Comment: what do you mean with "private"? as in class-private or as in invisible when retrieved?

Comment: @hasezoey like invisible when retrieved

Answer (score 1):

*as per the comment clarification of `private`*
you can set `select: false` as an prop option to not have it retrieved by default, you can activate it again by using [`.select('+your_prop_name')`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/decorators/prop/#select) in any query (like after an `.find` function)t (the property still gets saved to the db)

Note about typescript's `private`: this is just private for types, but public at runtime (and the new `#` private field is not yet tested with typegoose)